# How to use FontAwesome 5 with Chrome on Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

Using a Rails 6.1.4.1 app and trying to upgrade from FontAwesome 4 to 5.

`gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.15.1'`

In my `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` file:

```css
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
```

Using FA via the `icon` or via SCSS does not work for Chrome or Firefox. It does work fine in Safari.

Examples of how I'm using it:

```css
.btn-icon {
  @extend .btn;
  &:before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    padding-right: .5rem;
  }
}

.btn-new {
  @extend .btn-icon;
  @extend .btn-primary;
  &:before {
    content: "\f067";
  }
}
```

```rb
link_to icon('fas', 'cogs') + t(:quote_sheet_options), ''
```

The icons simply don't show in Chrome/FF - what's going on here?

**Update**

If I setup my css as shown below, it works. But I still can't use the `icon` helper to show any icons in my markup, and I can't show the icon by adding the markup manually either.

```css
.btn-icon {
  @extend .btn;
  &:before {
    @extend .fas;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    padding-right: .5rem;
  }
}

.btn-new {
  @extend .btn-icon;
  @extend .btn-primary;
  &:before {
    @extend .fa-plus;
  }
}
```

Comment: unicode to use can be different from a fontawesome version to another, so unicodes needs to be updated too.

Comment: I have checked that I'm using the proper unicode for each icon...

Comment: okay, is the link to the new version of fontawesome working, a typo maybe ? inspector tools should help you see the source code rendered.

Comment: I'm using the ruby gem, not a CDN link to FA.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [font_awesome5_rails](https://github.com/tomkra/font_awesome5_rails). The helper you will use is not `icon`, it is `fa_icon`. There are samples on font_awesome5_rails but here is one:

```rb
fa_icon('camera-retro', class: 'my-class', text: 'Camera', size: '3x')
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that gem. Not really wanting to go through this large project and change every place I've used `icon` though.